# How to convert PHP MD5 in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I couldn't find a concrete example for my problem

I need to convert this line PHP in NodeJS :

```
if (md5($value1.$value2.$value3.$value4.$value5) != $value)
```

I have used several things without success, like `CryptoJS.HmacMD5`, `CryptoJS.MD5` or `md5`

I feel it's a bit more complex with NodeJS, the values ​​correspond to queries in the url that I retrieve with `express`, `req.query.value_1` ...

Comment: Point of hashes is to be the same, wherever you create them so you can effectively compare them. That said, your error is not in MD5 function, but most likely in the variables. If you do `var_dump` in PHP and `console.log` in NodeJS and compare variable by variable, you will probably see a difference or two.

Comment: Yes very true I just noticed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const data = "value";
const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest("hex");

if (hash != "value") { }
```

PS: you don't need to install it as it already comes with Node

Answer (score 1):

Use `crypto` from `NPM`

```
npm i crypto
const crypto = require('crypto');
let strToMd5 = str1 + str2 + str4;
let hashedStr = crypto.createHash('md5').update(strToMd5).digest('hex');

if(hashedStr != value){
    // code
}
```